# ASP .Net MVC - Redirect view page from shared folder without shared controller in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a **Test.aspx** page which is containing in Shared folder. I dont have a shared controller.

In my main view page, When i get a result data like `Error` from `jquery $.ajax` means i want to redirect from main page to **Test.aspx** page.

How do i redirect the view page without corresponding controller & also How can i achieve this by using jquery?

```
window.location.href = "/path/";
```

Is it possible to redirect the view page without controller..

Answer (score 1):

> How do i redirect the view page without corresponding controller

Impossible and doesn't make sense. In ASP.NET MVC views cannot and shouldn't be served directly.

So you start by declaring a controller action that will return this view and inside your AJAX call you are simply pointing to it:

```
window.location.href = "somecontroller/someaction";
```

Comment: I have a doubt, From controller we can redirect to the view page(without controller) by using the code of `return View("Test");`. right?

Comment: No, this is not redirecting. This is rendering a view. There's a very big difference. Redirecting means performing another HTTP request. Rendering means that this view is executed under the current request.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot request a View directly from an MVC app without going through a Controller. It was never designed for that (and in most cases explicitly prevents it). That being said it is possible to switch what View is returned from a controller's action, in fact the default `HandleErrorAttribute` does this. Unlike a typical ASP.NET app, which redirects you to a page like error.aspx when an exception occurs, the `HandleErrorAttribute` takes a view name, and when an error occurs it returns that view. However it doesn't redirect you away from the page that you initially requested. So if you request a page to view a person's details (People/Details/123) and encounter an error, the URL will stay the same but the view returned will be that of the error view.

Keep in mind that the `HandleErrorAttribute` attribute will not handle errors that occur outside of MVC. So generic IIS and ASP.NET errors will not be handled by it.

If you want to redirect to an error view using javascript you should use the `HandleErrorAttribute`. If you want to have a full page not just a view, I'd recommend adding an action to the Home Controller (or even creating a controller called Errors) and request the page from that. If you don't like the idea of requesting a page using `/Home/Error` or `/Errors/Exception` you can always add a new route to the app so that it's shortened to just /Error or /Exception.

```
routes.MapRoute("ErrorPage", // Route name
                "Error", // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Error"});
```

or

```
routes.MapRoute("ExceptionPage", // Route name
                "Exception", // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "Errors", action = "Exception"});
```